# Why the CLR keeps checking static members for type constructor invocation even after the constructor invoked?

Tags: c#, .net, static, clr

I understand that when a type declares an explicit static constructor, the just-in-time (JIT) compiler adds a check to each static method and instance constructor of the type to make sure that the static constructor was previously called.

This behaviour I can imagine it as the following code (correct me please if I’m wrong with this conclusion):

```
class  ExplicitConstructor
    {
        private static string myVar;

        // Force “precise” initialization 
        static ExplicitConstructor() { myVar = "hello, world";} 
    
        
        /* CLR: if the type constructor didn't invoked 
                then add a call to the type constructor */
        public static string MyProperty
        {
            get { return myVar; }
        }
        
        /* CLR: if the type constructor didn't invoked 
                then add a call to the type constructor */
        public ExplicitConstructor()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("In instance ctor");
        }

    }

    class ImplicitConstructor 
    { 
        private static string myVar = "hello, world";
        
        public static string MyProperty
        {
            /* CLR: Invoke the type constructor only here */
            get { return myVar; }
        }
        
        public ImplicitConstructor()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("In instance ctor");
        }
    }
```

According to [performance rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1810), this behaive has an impact on the performance because of the checks that the runtime performs in order to run the type initializer at a precise time.

```
[MemoryDiagnoser]
[Orderer(SummaryOrderPolicy.FastestToSlowest)]
[RankColumn]
public class BenchmarkExample
{
    public const int iteration = Int32.MaxValue - 1;

    [Benchmark]
    public void BenchExplicitConstructor()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < iteration; i++)
        {
            var temp = ExplicitConstructor.MyProperty;
        }
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void BenchImplicitConstructor()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < iteration; i++)
        {
            var temp = ImplicitConstructor.MyProperty;
        }
    }

}
```

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Rank | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BenchImplicitConstructor | 982.6 ms | 56.64 ms | 163.4 ms | 1 | - |
| BenchExplicitConstructor | 7,361.4 ms | 318.19 ms | 933.2 ms | 2 | - |

Why did the CLR, instead of adding a check to each static method/instance constructor of the type to make sure that the type constructor was previously called, check if the type constructor had been invoked (only once)?

Comment: `Stopwatch` and `DateTime` is not an appropriate benchmarking tool... ever. Consider using BenchmarkDotNet for all benchmarking concerns first

Comment: @TheGeneral - Thanks. I've edited the question.

Comment: Could you please post the results of your benchmark?

Comment: @Clemens - Yes, I will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cost of checking that the static constructor has been called in ExplicitConstructor is exaggerated as the JIT has failed to optimise the check in the benchmark method - as shown with the JITd assembly generated by the BenchmarkDotNet `DisassemblyDiagnoser`.

```
; BenchExplicitConstructor()
       push      rsi
       sub       rsp,20
       xor       esi,esi

M00_L00: ; Hot loop
       mov       rcx,7FFE299E97C0
       mov       edx,6
       call      CORINFO_HELP_GETSHARED_NONGCSTATIC_BASE ; static check
       inc       esi
       cmp       esi,7FFFFFFE
       jl        short M00_L00

       add       rsp,20
       pop       rsi
       ret
```

Helping it out by ensuring ExplicitConstructor has been checked (and initialized in this case) before hitting the hot loop results in parity.

```cs
[Benchmark]
public void BenchExplicitConstructor()
{
    _ = ExplicitConstructor.MyProperty; // Explicitly check the class

    for (int i = 0; i < iteration; i++)
    {
        var temp = ExplicitConstructor.MyProperty;
    }
}
```

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Rank | Code Size | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BenchImplicitConstructor | 672.8 ms | 0.23 ms | 0.18 ms | 1 | 43 B | 3,992 B |
| BenchExplicitConstructor | 673.6 ms | 1.19 ms | 0.93 ms | 1 | 40 B | 384 B |

Why didn't the JIT do this by itself? <strike>In the context of one small piece of code, the appropriate heuristics weren't available for it to make the optimisation. It's highly unlikely this would be missed in the context of a normal program.</strike>

#### Update:

This is a known JIT issue covered by [#1327](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/1327), where the discussion [notes](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/1327#issuecomment-571255320) that methods containing loops skip quick JITing by default (see [tiered compilation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0#tiered-compilation)). This means an initial compilation that didn't hoist the static check (lift it out the loop body) is locked in for the lifetime of the program.

While this performance issue is currently unresolved, a cleaner work-around is mentioned in a related [feature request](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/3080#issuecomment-571285307); using a Fody attribute rather than a non-obvious call to manually hoist.

Comment: It seems like I was wrong about my conclusion; The `CORINFO_HELP_GETSHARED_NONGCSTATIC_BASE` call only happens If the .cctors have not yet been run), otherwise, there will be no call for it. Ex:


`static void Main() {_ = new ExplicitConstructor(); // CORINFO_HELP_GETSHARED_NONGCSTATIC_BASE
            Console.WriteLine(ExplicitConstructor.MyProperty); // No checks }`.


        

For the case (w/without `beforefieldinit`), and based on your answer, there seems two way to avoid this known JIT issue:
- Manually hoist the static checks.
- Using a Fody attribute.

Thanks You.

Comment: Close, but the JIT will only permamently fail to hoist when T0 generation is skipped, (EG. the method contains a loop) otherwise it remains a candidate for re-JITing later when it will recognise the class has been loaded and optimise accordingly.

Comment: If you need to mitigate this in production code and you're not already using Fody, I'd suggest an explicit Hoist method (plus doc comment for clarity) to avoid introducing the dependency. ([Demonstration](https://gist.github.com/TonuFish/9c80d7bc2d3b0def29b7ecd6c8e928cb)) Of interesting note, interacting with a `const` field _doesn't_ trigger a class check.